# Symplectic Chart

Tags: differential-geometry, banach-spaces, symplectic-geometry

I was reading the article "[Symplectic structures on Banach manifolds](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1969-75-05/S0002-9904-1969-12353-0/S0002-9904-1969-12353-0.pdf)" by Alan Weinstein. In this article there is one theorem, which is as following:

If $B$ is a zero neighborhood in Banach space. Let $\Omega$ be a symplectic form on this banach space.  Let $\Omega_1$ be the symplectic structure on $B$ which is constant
with respect to the natural parallelism on $B$ and equal to $\Omega$, at $0$ then...

I want to understand the meaning of natural parallelism here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *parallelism* (or *parallelization*) on a smooth manifold $M,$ modelled on a Banach space $\mathbb E,$ is determined by a global trivializing chart $\phi:TM\to M\times\mathbb E$ of its tangent bundle $\tau_M:v_p\in TM\mapsto p\in M.$

A smooth differential $k$-form $\omega$ on $M,$ is said to be *constant* w.r.t. the given parallelism when there exists $F,$ a bounded multilinear (alternating) $k$-form on $\mathbb E,$ such that $$\omega_{p}(v_1,\dots,v_k)=F(\phi|_p v_1,\dots,\phi|_p v_k),$$ for any $p\in M,$ and $v_1\dots,v_k\in T_pM.$

> The *natural parallelism* of an open subset  $U$ of $\mathbb E$ is the identity map of $TU=U\times\mathbb E.$

Note that, if there exists a parallelism on $M,$ then $M$ is called *parallelizable*.

**Edit** As a reference you can look at the entry "[Parallelism](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Parallelism,_absolute)" (originally written by D.Alekseevskii) in the EOM. Even if there are considered only finite-dimensional manifolds, the generalization is obvious.

Comment: Thnks for the answer.